# Empathy does not allow to add Facebook profile account

Tags: empathy

Empathy does not allow me to add my Facebook profile account in Ubuntu 13.04. It is showing the following error message. How can I resolve this? If anyone could help me?

Error Accessing App
We're sorry, but the application you're trying to use doesn't exist or has been disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Open System Settings, and click on Online Accounts. Then click on Add account... and choose Facebook. Login to it, and it should now work.

If facebook is already in that list, click Remove Account (Bottom right) and follow the instructions above to recreate it.

Comment: This is what he is trying to do, I have the same problem.